# what does <!-- in Javascript do?

Tags: javascript, symbols

It's so hard to search for symbols in Google, so I ask here instead.

`<!--` looks like a comment for me, but it doesn't work like html. Or it's a one line comment just like `//` ?

What is the purpose and benefit of using this? Thanks

sample code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    alert("example");
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of where you saw it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an old method of hiding JavaScript from browsers that would treat the text node of a `script` element as normal text (and display your code).

[Douglas Crockford recommends](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html) you don't use it anymore.

> Do not use the `<!-- //-->` hack with scripts. It was intended to prevent scripts from showing up as text on the first generation browsers Netscape 1 and Mosaic. It has not been necessary for many years. `<!-- //-->` is supposed to signal an HTML comment. Comments should be ignored, not compiled and executed. Also, HTML comments are not to include `--`, so a script that decrements has an HTML error.

Comment: now it all make sense.. It's an existing codes and it's everywhere. So will just leave them there.

Answer (score 0):

Comments in html

- `<!-- ... -->`

Comments in javascript are like c:

- One line comment   = `// ...`
- Multi line comment = `/* ... */`

Answer (score 0):

It is HTML -- it's an HTML comment.  Often used in a JavaScript block for CDATA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript treats `<!--` as a single line comment, the same as `//`. This is so you can wrap your JS code such that it looks like an HTML comment to browsers that don't understand JS:

```
<script>
    <!--
    alert('test');
    // -->
</script>
```

Comment: No it doesn't. In fact your answer doesn't make sense. Javascript executes the code inside. *HTML* treats it as a comment.

Comment: @EJP: HTML only treats it as a comment if your browser doesn't understand Javascript or the `<script>` tag at all. This hasn't been the case in any semi-popular browser for over a decade now. Which means that the statement in the answer is correct, though I'm not sure it's treated as a single-line comment. I believe that the symbol is simply ignored by most Javascript engines if it is at the start of a `<script>` block.

Comment: @Matthew it's treated as single line comment in chrome. I tried it out in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phelios/wuCMD/)

Comment: @Matthew Scharley: that doesn't change the fact that Javascript doesn't treat it as a comment at all. Otherwise the entire construct would be pointless.

Comment: @Phelios the part about treating it as a comment is nonsense. If it did that the entire construct would be pointless. More probably it is simply *ignored* by Javascript, if it gets to see it, like most other errors in Javascript.

Comment: @EJP, it's treated as a **single line** comment.